# how to call the query to insert the data into table where its has foreign key to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two table inside my database. One is order table and food table. Food table is linked with order table where the order_id is foreign key for food.

Order

```
Order_ID | Customer_ID | Time_Delivery | Date_Delivery | Total
```

Food

```
Order_ID | Food_item_id | Cart_quantity
```

What way can I use to insert the data into food table where the order_Id is linked to order table.
I using with the query but I have no idea what can I use to define the $orderid.

**Food php**

```
$foodname=$_POST["food_name"];
$cartquantity=$_POST["cart_quantity"];
query= insert into Food (food_item_id,Cart_quantity) values 
('$fooditemid','$cartquantity') where $orderid= ;
```

**Order php**

```
$id=$_POST["id"];
$pickuptime=$_POST["pick_up_time"];
$pickupdate=$_POST["pick_up_date"];
$amount=$_POST["amount"];


$mysqli_qry="insert into `order` (`id`,`pickuptime`,`pickupdate`,`amount`) 
values ($id,$pickuptime,$pickupdate,$amount)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can stor last inseted order id in var and insert into food table. Kindly check below

```
insert into `order` (`id`,`pickuptime`,`pickupdate`,`amount`) 
values ($id,$pickuptime,$pickupdate,$amount)"; 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into Food (food_item_id,Cart_quantity) values 
('$fooditemid','$cartquantity') where $orderid=@last_id_in_table1 ;
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Can I use set last insert id in two PHP? Mean I use it at the order PHP then I call it at food PHP